# Unable to retrieve result for Job Error during VQE simulation

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, simulation, vqe

I am attempting to run a VQE calculation on the 'ibmq_qasm_simulator'. The job is failing with a series of errors caused by:

```
qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.exceptions.IBMQJobApiError: "Unable to retrieve result for job 5f46829baa801d001a09d0d7: '404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/Network/ibm-q/Groups/open/Projects/main/Jobs/5f46829baa801d001a09d0d7/resultDownloadUrl. Cannot get presigned download url., Error code: 3202.'"
```

I have used the same code on the statevector simulator successfully. I have copied the full error message below:

```
FAILURE: Can not get job id, Resubmit the qobj to get job id. Terra job error: 'Error submitting job: \'(\\\'Connection aborted.\\\', OSError("(110, \\\'ETIMEDOUT\\\')"))\'' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/session.py", line 250, in request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/Network/ibm-q/Groups/open/Projects/main/Jobs/5f46829baa801d001a09d0d7/resultDownloadUrl

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/job/ibmqjob.py", line 856, in _retrieve_result
    result_response = self._api.job_result(self.job_id(), self._use_object_storage)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/clients/account.py", line 243, in job_result
    return self._job_result_object_storage(job_id)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/clients/account.py", line 263, in _job_result_object_storage
    download_url = job_api.result_url()['url']
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/rest/job.py", line 147, in result_url
    return self.session.get(url).json()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/session.py", line 270, in request
    raise RequestsApiError(message) from ex
qiskit.providers.ibmq.api.exceptions.RequestsApiError: '404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/Network/ibm-q/Groups/open/Projects/main/Jobs/5f46829baa801d001a09d0d7/resultDownloadUrl. Cannot get presigned download url., Error code: 3202.'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OH-_iqs_length.py", line 90, in <module>
    ret = vqe.run(quantum_instance)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/quantum_algorithm.py", line 70, in run
    return self._run()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/minimum_eigen_solvers/vqe.py", line 362, in _run
    optimizer=self.optimizer)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/vq_algorithm.py", line 201, in find_minimum
    gradient_function=gradient_fn)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/components/optimizers/slsqp.py", line 87, in optimize
    options=self._options)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 618, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 423, in _minimize_slsqp
    g = append(fprime(x), 0.0)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 327, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py", line 63, in approx_jacobian
    jac[i] = (func(*((x0+dx,)+args)) - f0)/epsilon
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 327, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/algorithms/minimum_eigen_solvers/vqe.py", line 450, in _energy_evaluation
    sampled_expect_op = self._circuit_sampler.convert(self._expect_op, params=param_bindings)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/operators/converters/circuit_sampler.py", line 194, in convert
    param_bindings=param_bindings)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/operators/converters/circuit_sampler.py", line 272, in sample_circuits
    had_transpiled=self._transpile_before_bind)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/quantum_instance.py", line 374, in execute
    self._skip_qobj_validation, self._job_callback)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/utils/run_circuits.py", line 302, in run_qobj
    results.append(job.result(**qjob_config))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/job/ibmqjob.py", line 276, in result
    return self._retrieve_result(refresh=refresh)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/job/ibmqjob.py", line 869, in _retrieve_result
    'job {}: {}'.format(self.job_id(), str(err))) from err
qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.exceptions.IBMQJobApiError: "Unable to retrieve result for job 5f46829baa801d001a09d0d7: '404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/Network/ibm-q/Groups/open/Projects/main/Jobs/5f46829baa801d001a09d0d7/resultDownloadUrl. Cannot get presigned download url., Error code: 3202.'"
```

How can i do about fixing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While it's not always helpful, you can find solutions for most error codes here: https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/docs/manage/errors

In your case since you're running with Qiskit Aqua, it automatically re-submitted the job, as indicated by

```
FAILURE: Can not get job id, Resubmit the qobj to get job id.
```

So your VQE calculation should resume once the new job finishes.